# jQuery function doesn't return value to Variable

Tags: jquery, function

I am trying to return a value in jQuery and replace the Text of a div. The console.log() in my Function logs the correct value, but the Function returns nothing to my Variable (d) which should replace the Text in the div.

Here is my Code Sample:

```
var d = getLatLong('Bahnhofplatz, 8000 Zürich');
$('#divResult').replaceWith(d);

//$("#divResult").replaceWith("asdsadsadsad");

function getLatLong(address) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        address : address, 
        region: 'no'
    },
    function(results, status) {
        if (status.toLowerCase() == 'ok') {
            var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(
                results[0]['geometry']['location'].lat(),
                results[0]['geometry']['location'].lng()
                );
            var latlng = 'Latitute: ' + coords.lat() + '    Longitude: ' + coords.lng();
            console.log(latlng);
            return latlng;
            }
        }
    );
};
```

And here is a "working" jsFiddle link:

**http://jsfiddle.net/u3rgocms/1/**

Thank you for your Help.

Comment: could you not just do [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/u3rgocms/6/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work because you return the value in the inner function that is called in the geocoder scope. You could just put the replace function in where you return the string. Keep in mind that the result function if the geocode call will be called asynchronously. This is implemented as an unblocking function so your primary business logik won't wait until the response is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your Help.

The working code for me is:

```
getLatLong('Bahnhofplatz, 8000 Zürich', function(x){
    $('#divResult').replaceWith(x[0]);
});

//$("#divResult").replaceWith("asdsadsadsad");

function getLatLong(address, callback) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        address : address, 
        region: 'no'
    },
    function(results, status) {
        if (status.toLowerCase() == 'ok') {
            var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(
                results[0]['geometry']['location'].lat(),
                results[0]['geometry']['location'].lng()
                );
            var latlng = [coords.lat() , coords.lng()];
            callback(latlng);
            }
        }
    );
};
```